# Using TShark via cmd in c# doesnt terminate when Pcap file is too big. Why is that?

Tags: c#, cmd, tshark

I want to use Tshark in C#. So I wrote an executor class like this:

```
public class CommandExecutor : IDisposable
    {
        Process cmd = new Process();

        public string ExecuteCmdCommand(string command)
        {
            string envVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", envVariable + @";C:\Program Files\Wireshark");

            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/C {command}";
            cmd.Start();

            cmd.WaitForExit();
            return cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            cmd.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

And I am calling it with this method:

```
public string ReadCaptureFile(string fileName) => ExecuteCmdCommand($"tshark -r {fileName}");
```

This works fine for smaller pcap files. I´ve tested it with a pcap file with 32 packets and i receive the wanted output.

But when I try to read bigger files e.g. one that has 216 packets, the process just wont terminate. The console window opens but doesnt show any output. Also I cant close it by pressing enter.

Does anyone know why this happens? Did I do something wrong? (I certainly did, but I dont see where)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a fix that works for me.

I just set a timer value of 0.1 seconds in the WaitForExit method.

`Cmd.WaitForExit(100);`

I dont know if this is the best way to do it but it works.